# Custom people refinement panel not displaying all filter options

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a custom people refinement panel thats set to display all the "values" available for a filter called CUSLocation. I have about 45 items in that one filter.

The filter displays 44 locations, but not the 45th one. It is very weird. The filter is sorted by Ascending order, but won't display "Downtown".

But when I frame the URL like this https://sp.example.com/Pages/company-directory.aspx?r=CUSlocation="Downtown" the "Downtown" option is displayed in the refinement panel.

CUSlocation is metadata property mapped to our active directory.

Any idea why this could be happening with people refinement panel?

```
<Category Title="Location" Description="Use this filter to restrict results to a specific Location"        Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator"        MetadataThreshold="50"           MaxNumberOfFilters="0"        SortBy="Name"        SortDirection="Ascending"    SortByForMoreFilters="Name"    SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Ascending"    ShowMoreLink="True"        MappedProperty="CUSLocation"        MoreLinkText="show more"        LessLinkText="show fewer"/>
```

Comment: You could try posting this question on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/, you might get an answer there.

Comment: You could try to look at the metadata dataset, there might be an errant character like {*',"-} or space in the location name that is stopping it from being rendered properly.